# PHP: How to write a message to show up in 'ps' command?

Tags: php, sleep, ps

If I write a Bash shell program with a sleep statement, I can do the following to check on it's status:

```
ps aux | grep sleep
```

If I have a sleep occur for a long period of time, such as 10 minutes in PHP to try to see if a network connection is now available, I can't determine if the program is having a problem or it's correctly executing the sleep function.

One method I was thinking, was to write the sleep state with a timestamp to a log file. But I wondered if it was possible and practical to be able to write this status so it would show up doing a 'ps aux | grep sleep' that this php programming running is asleep at the moment.

Or is there a better method and approach to this? Thanks!

Comment: what's this mystery php script suppose to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a sleep-php.sh then execute it with the bash command, I think it is `source sleep-php.sh`. Then you can grep for sleep-php.sh without risking to confuse it with a different sleep command that happens to run by accident.

You can even go further and dynamically create the "sleep-php-$id.sh" so you can include more information with the sleep, here am id as example.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best approach is not to place your tracker/logger at a lower level, the OS's, but rather in the PHP itself.

What I would suggest is to write a PHP loop, with a finite number of attempts, and a shorter waiting period between attempts, this way you can log each loop, and the result of your network connection poll at every loop.
As soon as your connection network is acquired, break from the loop.
If the loop if finished and no network access has been obtained, issue a relevant message / business action.

```
define("MAX_ATTEMPT_COUNT", 10);
define("WAITING_TIME", 60);

$NetworkAccess = false;

$fd = fopen("netpoll.log", 'a');
if (!$fd) die("I thought I could open netpoll.log but I can't.");

for($i=1; $i<=MAX_ATTEMPT_COUNT; $i++) {
    fwrite($fd, "Entering loop #" . $i);

    $NetworkAccess |= pollNetwork(); // can be |= or simply =

    if ($NetworkAccess) {
        fwrite($fd, "network access acquired, exiting loop.");
        break;
    }

    fwrite($fd, "No cigar, I'll try again in " . WAITING_TIME . " seconds.");
    sleep(WAITING_TIME);
} 

if(!$NetworkAccess) {
    fwrite($fd, "No network access after " . MAX_ATTEMPT_COUNT*WAITING_TIME . " seconds, giving up.");
}

fclose($fd);
```